# PIL crop image takes enormous amounts of space

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an array of `PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile` it takes around 50mb of space which seems fair (image size is always 1654x2339).

Now I need to crop these images. So I tried:

```
arr = [i.crop((120,0,w-100,h-100)) for i in arr]
```

I end up with an array of `PIL.Image._ImageCrop` that takes over 1.2 gb of memory. Based on a previous question I'm guessing there are some temp operations that create a bunch of temp objects but I'm not sure. Is there any other way to crop and store?

Comment: You say your array takes over 1.2 gb (though I suspect you mean 1.2GB), but how am I supposed to know if that's a lot when I don't know how big it was before cropping, nor how many images are in it?

Comment: Please use **MB** for megabytes in accordance with the ISO standard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte - rather than **mb** which would mean *"millibits"* by the same standard. Pretty much only hardware and RF engineers speak in *"bits"* such as 50 Gb/s bandwidth because they correlate to GHz and frequencies that such people normally deal with. Software folk normally use multiples of **bytes**, e.g. **kB**, **MB**, **GB**.